# Let $U$ be the set of all $n×n$ matrices with real entries such that all their eigenvalues belong to $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R $.

Tags: general-topology, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $U$ be the set of all $n×n$ matrices with real entries such that
>   all their eigenvalues belong to $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R  $, and
>   $X = M_n(\mathbb R)$. Is $U$ open?

[I know that set of all $2×2$ matrices with real entries such that
 all their eigenvalues belong to $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R  $, and
 $X = M_2(\mathbb R)$ is open subset of  $M_2(\mathbb R).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2715697/u-be-the-set-of-all-2%C3%972-matrices-with-real-entries-such-that-all-their-eigen/2715762#comment6255905_2715762)

For $n$ odd $U$ is open. Since characteristic polynomial is of odd degree, Hence it must be having at least one real zero. So, $U=\emptyset$. Hence, $U$ is open. What about the other case?  When $n$ is even, How do I connect characteristic polynomial and nature of roots? For quadratic equations, it is an easy task.

Comment: Here is a suggestion: The roots of the characteristic polynomial come in conjugate pairs with non-zero imaginary parts, and for any given matrix you can find a positive $\epsilon$ such that $|\operatorname{Im} \lambda| > \epsilon$. Argue that small perturbations in the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial (or equivalently, small perturbations in the matrix components) lead to small perturbations in the roots.

Comment: Sounds like a nice exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A \in U$. If $A$ is not an interior point of $U$ then there exists matrices $A_n$ converging to $A$ such that each $A_n$ has  a real eigen value $\lambda_n$. There exist unit vectors $x_n$ such that $A_nx_n=\lambda_n x_n$. Since the unit sphere is compact there is a subsequence $(x_{n'})$ converging to a unit vector $x$. Now, $A_{n'}x_{n'}\to Ax$ and the equation$A_{n'}x_{n'}=\lambda_{n'}x_{n'}$ shows that $\lambda_{n'}$ must converge. The limit $\lambda$ is a real number and we get the contradiction $Ax=\lambda x$.

Comment: Very good answer. Thank you.